# System.Web.UI.Page GC occurrs on refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I've got some custom controls on a dynamically build web page that can have delegates added to their event handlers as the page loads.

If the page is refreshed, do I need to worry about leaking memory due to adding these event handlers each time the page loads, or does everything in the page gets GCd?

I seem to think that the "page" gets gc'd every time it's loaded and the only items that persist are things like session variables, but that comes from when I was doing stuff in PHP.  I'm wondering if anyone has anything concrete on this for c#/asp.net.

*APPEND*:

My delegates are only looking and interacting with specific controls on the page at the time for example,  when one control is changed, another control is defaulted to select a corresponding value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time user makes a request to ASP.NET webserver new instance of Page class is created and it walks through the lifecycle. So if you have some properties, they are initialized with their default values. Afterwards the modified Page is being rendered to HTML and returned to the user. It is not completely clear of what delegates you add, so a piece of code may be helpful, but I don't think you should have any problems.

So the Page is recreated, Session data is being taken by the session cookie, Viewstate data by special input hidden field.

Page Life Cycle may be helpful for you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Sorry I can't really give you a meaningful code example due to obfuscation, but I presume only interacting with controls on the same page shouldn't cause an issue (from your answer) ?

Comment: In .NET everything in the heap withour a reference gets GCd. If you added some handlers to the page, those handlers will not be there during next postback unless you add them again. Old Page instance is gone - forget about it.

Comment: But obviously during one page life cycle (when you work with one Page instance) you should be concerned about all the handlers you attach. Does that make sense?